# Derivation of the advection equation

Tags: conservation-laws, continuum-mechanics, transport-phenomena

In this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection), specifically in the section "Mathematics of advection", the following general equation for advection is given as:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\psi u)=\sigma
\end{equation}

Being a continuity equation, it's not hard to understand what it's saying. But I want know how to derive it, formally.

Comment: You are comfortable with the WP derivation of the divergence less flow advection, i.e. solenoidal velocity?

Comment: "In the field of physics, engineering, and earth sciences, advection is the transport of a substance or quantity by bulk motion of a fluid."